# how to insert elements single array into multidimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have been trying with no luck to combine one array into another, multidimensional array.  The first array, **$id1**, is created from a mySQL query.  The second array, **$pictures1**, is created with scandir and will hold up to 24 .jpg file pointers.  I have tried array_merge, array_splice, among others, and a variety of looping functions.  All to no avail. I have read the many forums on combining arrays with no luck.  I'm new to PHP, and i think I'm missing something basic here.  I would appreciate any direction or insight on the correct way to go.  These are the arrays:

$pictures1

```
Array
   (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => boxer1.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        [0] => boxer2.jpg
        )
    )
```

$id1

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [car_id] => 6
        [alt_img] => boxer
    )
```

)

I am trying to merge them to create a new array **$pix**
The final should look like this:

```
array(
     array( 'car_id' => '6', 'pic_lg' => 'boxer1.jpg', 'alt_img' => 
     'boxer'),
     array( 'car_id' => '6', 'pic_lg' => 'boxer2.jpg', 'alt_img' => 
     'boxer'),
     etc...
```

Thank you.

Comment: do the 2 arrays have the same count of elements? Which one is the primary array?

Comment: No, $id1 has two elements ['car_id'] and ['img_alt']  $pictures1 (depending on the number of .jpg to upload), can have from 1 to 24. thank you.

Comment: So, which one of the 24 should be taken?

Comment: however many could be in the array...could be up to 24 in the multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your informations, this could be an approach:

```
$pix = array();
for ($i=0; $i<count($id1);$i++) {

    $pix[$i]  = $id[$i];
    $pix[$i]['pic_lg'] = $pictures1[$i][0];

}
var_dump($pix);
```

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [alt_img] => boxer
            [pic_lg] => boxer1.jpg
        )

)  this works, but doesn't pick up more than one row of the $pictures array

Comment: So, how do the 24 pics get orded to the main array? Is there any ruleset for this?

Comment: no ruleset.  I use scandir to grab the directory contents of .jpg files that another process place in this directory.  The array is spliced to remove the . and ..  Then I use array_filter and array_chunk to transform it into a multidimensional array.  (when I have manually created this array, the upload process to mysql seems to like the format as in my third code posting above).  This loops works great, but only picks up and merges the first element.  I'm still new to PHP, and am trying to make it loop through as many of the files that reside in the directory, and complete the array. Tx!